# Trying to get object from CosmosDb via MVC app via client.CreateDocumentQuery

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

First attempt at accessing Cosmos db.

All this is in a DAL project layer of the solution (n-tier).
EndPointURI and PrimaryKey and DBName are setup by the class constructor.

I execute the client.CreateDocumentQuery

But not seeing the expected cast to the out param of the function i.e. "user".
I see the generated query string only.

I'm basing my code on [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-azure-cosmos-db-in-mvc-web-application/)

```
public void  GetUserByEmail(string email, out IQueryable<Shared.User> user)
    {
        FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 };
        user = null;

        try
        { 
            user = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<Shared.User>(
                       UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DBName, "Users"), queryOptions)
                       .Where(f => f.Email == email);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
```

[image]

If trying ReadDocumentAsync, I get the following
[image]

Comment: Have you tried executing the query in portal? with same email id?

Comment: SELECT * FROM c shows me my json, i.e.
{
    "UserName": "nroger@iafrica.com",
    "Email": "nroger@iafrica.com",
    "Password": "P@ssw0rd1",
    "Role": {
        "id": "1",
        "Role": "Admin"
    },
    "id": "d3e4351d-79fc-469f-8c22-8735e6f3fe71"
}

Comment: add the where clause and see if its returning the data

Comment: If I use 
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE c.id = "d3e4351d-79fc-469f-8c22-8735e6f3fe71"   then it works in the portal, but it won't allow me to specify the where with the emailaddress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you need to return the first item

```
 var response = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<eUser>( UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("demo", "Users"), queryOptions) 
.Where(f => f.Email == email).AsEnumerable().ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
```